# Scala how to escape 3 double quotes

Tags: string, scala, escaping, multilinestring

```
val s = """ """Shom """
```

gives

:1: error: ';' expected but string literal found.
val s = """ """Shom"""

Tried to escape

```
val s = """ ""\"Shom """
```

result is not as expected.

s: String = " ""\"Shom"

Comment: `"\"\"\"Shom"` is one way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Try with [`s` string interpolator](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html#the-s-string-interpolator)

```scala
val tripleQuote = """""""""  // 9 quotes in total
s"""${tripleQuote}Shom"""
res2: String = """Shom
```

or even inline it

```
s"""${"""""""""}Shom"""


s"""${List.fill(3)('"').mkString}Shom"""


s"""${"\""*3}Shom"""
```

which all output

```
"""Shom
```

because `s` String interpolators can take arbitrary expressions

```
s"meaning is ${41 + 1}"
// res4: String = meaning is 42
```